# If G/Z(G) is abelian, then H/Z(H) is also abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H be a subgroup of G. If G/Z(G) is abelian, then H/Z(H) is also abelian.

I am trying to prove this property yet I don't know how I should proceed. Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: What can you say about $H/(H\cap Z(G))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_1,h_2\in H$, then you want to show that $h_1Z(H)h_2Z(H) = h_2Z(H)h_1Z(H)$.

Equivalently, since $Z(H)$ commutes with everything in $H$, you want to show that $h_1h_2Z(H) = h_2h_1Z(H)$, in other words, you want to show $h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2\in Z(H)$.

However, $h_1,h_2$ are also in $G$, and you know that since $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, $h_1h_2Z(G) = h_2h_1Z(G)$, ie $h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2Z(G) = Z(G)$, so $h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2\in Z(G)$, so it commutes with everything in $G$, and hence in particular it commutes with everything in $H$. On the other hand, $h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}h_1h_2\in H$, so it must be in $Z(H)$.